# EKCalendar showing events "Found in Natural Language" which are not in Apple Calendar

Tags: swift, calendar, ekevent, ekcalendar

I am currently reading all calendar events with a function similar to what is described here: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/04/28/listing-calendar-events-with-event-kit-and-swift/

i.e.

```
        // Use an event store instance to create and properly configure an NSPredicate
        let eventsPredicate = eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, calendars: [calendar])

        // Use the configured NSPredicate to find and return events in the store that match
        self.events = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(eventsPredicate).sort(){
            (e1: EKEvent, e2: EKEvent) -> Bool in
            return e1.startDate.compare(e2.startDate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
        }
```

Now on my iPhone X running iOS 12.1.1 this gives me the various events of a calendar called 'Found in Natural Language'. I know that those are supposed to be the events, which Siri found in apps like Mail etc. I turned this option on under the iPhone Settings -> Calendar. However, the strange thing is that Apple's iOS calendar doesn't show these events, even though the found by Siri calendar is turned on. Some calendar apps like Fantastical don't show them either, and some other apps, like e.g. Vantage calendar show them.

How can that be?

Comment: Same problem; did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well.  A friend had sent an email to me mentioning their Wedding Anniversary.  Siri had found it and had tagged it as being something I could add to my calendar.  I hadn’t originally spotted that in ‘mail’ and neither had Fantastical or Apple Calendar, but Vantage had.  So I think Vantage is displaying items suggested by Siri whereas it should only be displaying items that have been found and then accepted and added to a calendar.